# How to install libanimation

Tags: compiz

As complete Ubuntu noob I was wondering if anyone knows how to install libanimation from github on Ubuntu 18.10. Thanks! :D

Comment: I think it's not ready yet. You might like to read [Wobbly Windows Are Making a Comeback - OMG! Ubuntu!](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/09/wobbly-windows-new-libanimation-linux-library)

Comment: What about [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/9zqlon/some_fun_with_libanimation/) thread?

Comment: @Kulfy they've had a couple releases now: https://github.com/endlessm/libanimation/releases . I guess what's missing iss a UI to utilize it. the question stands though : even without, ui how do you use this lib? also it's not in repos yet even though canonical is the maintainer.